# Reference member function in setInterval

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, closures

I have a backbone model that looks somewhat like this:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    watch : function() {
        this.watcher = setInterval("this.refetch", 5000);
    }

    refetch : function() {
        //do something
    }
});
```

The `setInterval` method doesn't actually work, because, I suppose, `this.refetch` isn't valid in the `setInterval` call. Neither does `setInterval("refetch", 5000);` work.

What I'm doing right now is this:

```
watch : function() {
    var that = this;
    setInterval(function(){
        that.refetch();
    }, 5000);   
}
```

Is there a better way to do this, so that I don't need to use `that`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Backbone already brings underscore.js with it, use it.  In your case, context can be bound to interval function with `_.bind`:

```
setInterval( _.bind( function(){this.refetch();}, this), 5000);
```

This is better approach not only because it's shorter, but also because it prevents `that` alias from beeing visible in nested scopes which can cause all sorts of hard-to-catch bugs.  See idiomatic.js style guide, "Faces of this" section: https://github.com/rwldrn/idiomatic.js/

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are doing right now i.e,

```
 function() {
var that = this;
setInterval(function(){
    that.refetch();
}, 5000);   
}
```

is itself a better approach.!!

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't exist inside your interval.  If you need access to whatever `this` is you need to pass it in to an anonymous function in a closure, like so:

```
setInternval( (
  return function(obj){
     obj.refetch();
  }(this)

) , 5000)
```